# How to delete duplicated columns in a tibble in the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

Let's say my data has two identical columns called SYC SJ Equity. When I import this into R using the base `read.csv()` and setting `check.names` to `FALSE`, the data gets imported with two columns having identical names. I can then delete the duplicated columns like so:

```r
df <- df %>% 
  do(.[!duplicated(names(.))])
```

If I use the `read_csv()` function from the readr to import the data, the duplicated column gets the column name in the form of "SYC SJ Equity_1". I can then do the following to delete the duplicated column

```r
df <- df %>%
  select(-contains("_"))
```

However, if the data is in a sheet in a `.xlsx` format, and I use the `read_excel()` function from the `readxl` package, the duplicated column gets imported as:

```r
New names:
* `SYC SJ Equity` -> `SYC SJ Equity...406`
* `SYC SJ Equity` -> `SYC SJ Equity...407`
```

In this case, both columns get renamed, whereas with `read_csv()`, only the extra instance(s) gets renamed. In this case, I have to match the entire string to delete the duplicated column. I do not know what numbers will get assigned to the duplicated columns. I assume it's based on the column index? Furthermore, even with the `read_csv()` import, my solution won't work if my columns all naturally have underscores in their names in the raw data. So my question is, how do I delete a duplicated column in the tidyverse with data stored in tibbles? This is easy with base R, with `duplicated()`. But this doesn't work with the tibbles of the tidyverse. I understand that `dplyr` verbs select by column name and not by column index,so the column names always have to be different. But is there a way to always deleted the duplicated column with tidyverse, without looking at the console to see the new duplicated names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off the answer provided by Ronak, if you want to do this in `dplyr`, then you can just use his provided solution with `select_if`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("x" = runif(3),
                 "SYC SJ Equity...406" = c("a", "a", "b"), 
                 "SYC SJ Equity...407" = c("a", "a", "b"), 
                 "y" = runif(3))

df %>%
  select_if(!duplicated(sub("\\.\\.\\..*", "", names(.))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you do not have any columns whose names actually includes 3 dots (`...`). We can read the data into R and remove those 3 dots from the names, use `duplicated` to find repetitive names and select the unique columns.

```
df[, !duplicated(sub("\\.\\.\\..*", "", names(df)))]
```

Just to show how it works on a vector

```
x <- c("y", "SYC SJ Equity...406", "SYC SJ Equity...407", "x")
x[!duplicated(sub("\\.\\.\\..*", "", x))]
#[1] "y"                   "SYC SJ Equity...406" "x"
```

So it keeps `"x"` and `"y"` columns as it is and select only the first duplicated value.

Answer (score 1):

Or with `select_if` and `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    select_if(!duplicated(str_remove(names(.), '\\..*')))
```